# var_dump displays text, but echo does not

Tags: php, echo, var-dump

I have an array called `$worker`
the array consists of only strings, each of which has multiple lines.

if I do

```
var_dump($worker);
```

it displays all the information, but do

```
for($i=0,$size=sizeof($worker);$i<$size;++$i)
{
    echo $worker[i];
}
```

I end up with nothing on the page.

I'm very new to php, so sorry if this is a noob question:
how do I get the information in the array to print to the screen correctly?

Comment: You probably just forgot the `$` in `i` in `$worker[i]`.

Comment: Enable on-screen display of warnings in your development environment, and you'll notice these mistakes right away.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the '$' for your '$i' variable inside the `for` loop.

It's a good idea to turn on error reporting while developing in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

This is the conventional syntax for `for` loops in PHP:

```
for ($i=0, $c=count($worker); $i<$c; $i++) {
    echo $worker[$i];
}
```

Comment: A little more detail on what is actually going wrong with the missing $.  When PHP sees `$worker[i]` it thinks that `i` is a bare string instead of a variable. Since there is no constant named `i` it converts `i` into a string and tries to access `$worker['i']` since PHP arrays work like associative arrays. Since `$worker['i']` hasn't been set it returns `null`.  `echo null` prints an empty string.  Also, as the code @asdf posted points out in PHP it is customary to use `count` instead of `sizeof`, `sizeof` is just an alias of `count`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=0,$size=count($worker);$i<$size;++$i)
{
echo $worker[$i];
}
```

You forgot '$' int echo $worker[$i];

Comment: @motsu: coming from c++ you find PHP as the paradise.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the dollar sign before i in `$worker[$i]`.

-edit-: Removed the second part, maybe I'm too tired :)

Comment: The second part is nonsense as its return value is not used.